# C++: best way to get size of object in generic code

Tags: c++, templates

I'm writing a template class which calls a hash function which takes as argument a pointer to an object and that object's size.

For example, if `item` is of type `int`, the call would be
`MurmurHash2(&item, sizeof(item), seed);`
But if `item` is an `std::string`, we would have to do
`MurmurHash2(item.c_str(), item.size(), seed);`

What's the cleanest way to write this code so that it can handle as many types as possible?

Comment: Don not do it, be specific. See std::hash

Comment: Use `sizeof` for sizes. Anyway, unless you can guarantee the binary layout on two systems is identical, you cannot guarantee getting the same hash. Still, look at `std::hash` and how they solved the second problem with template specializations.

Comment: @Deduplicator: That is a horrible advice... (The whole approach is broken), take for example: `struct T { char ch; int value; } a = {'a', 1}, b = {'a', 1};`, will you get the same hash for `a` and `b`? **No**, not if you use a pointer to the object and the size because by blindly looking at all bits you include padding whose value is undetermined by the language.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: That's part of the binary layout, and why specialiations are neccessary. How do you think `std::hash` does it?

Comment: @Deduplicator:  Can't use `sizeof` for strings, vectors or other containers.  `sizeof(std::string)` does not return the number of letters in the string, but the size of the controlling data structure.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I understand the problem, but given the question, suggesting `sizeof` (instead of pointing out the flaws in the approach) is not helping Matt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution: use something like [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) to convert your objects into a standardised stream of bytes, and then pass it to the MurmurHash function along with the size.

Answer (score 5):

Your solution is inherently flawed, you **cannot** create a hash function by taking a pointer to the beginning of the object and the size of the object and expect that to work. Consider a simple type and two variables:

```
struct T {
   char ch;
   int  i;
} a = { 'a', 1 }, b = { 'a', 1 };
```

In my current platform (and I imagine in most platforms), `sizeof(T) == 8` of which only 5 bytes are part of the *value* of the object, and the other 3 are *padding*. The value of the bytes in the padding are not guaranteed to have any value and chances are that they will differ in `a` and `b`, even though the two objects hold the same value.

Comment: Also consider when a structure contains a pointer, such `std::vector`.

Comment: You **can** expect it to work. If all pre-conditions are satisfied on the platform. That means, only a single representation for each value, and all the data in the structure itself. Sure, that depends on the data you want to hash, what else is new? There's template specialization.

Comment: @Deduplicator: No, reread the answer. In most platforms (all?) objects may have both internal and external padding, the bits in the padding hold undefined values. Using `sizeof` on the `T` in the answer will make the hash algorithm consider 8 bytes, 3 of which have *random* values. The values of the `a` and `b` objects is the same, but a hash using all 8 bytes can yield different results. Unless you really meant to say that you can use `sizeof` for *integral types* and objects containing only those and no padding; that's all (not even all fundamental types, floating point are weird beasts)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: **only a single representation for a vlaue**. If you can guarantee the padding bytes have consistent values, their existence does not matter. Otherwise, you have multiple representations, so the preconditions are not met and a specialization is neccessary. Please read the whole comment.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Can you guarantee **in C++** the value of the padding? Given that **no** is the answer then any object with padding does not have a single representation, and given an unknown type `T` you can expect that **not** to work (the universe of objects for which it would work is far smaller than the universe of objects for which it will fail). *You can expect it to work* is misleading the user into believing that it will often times work, rather than it will work in *rare* occasions

Comment: Depends on how the struct was initialized.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Think about the requirements that you are implicitly expecting and whether the comment to the question even *hints* at them. Also note that this does not only depend on how the `struct` was initialized, you might need an allocator to wipe out the memory (or write the *padding*) before calling a constructor. If your claim is *it can work in a few cases*, the answer is yes, but you **cannot expect** this to work (without adding a huge amount of restrictions that the user might not even be able to understand --assuming he did not know `sizeof` I won't assume he knows the rest).

Comment: If the same value can have multiple representations, than hashing it all is not good, which is the reason `std::hash` is specialized for some types and can be specialized for more types. Otherwise, it's good, so use `sizeof` for the size. Where do you disagree? Anyway, putting all that in your answer would be good.

Comment: But the OP never implies that the solution must use `sizeof` - in fact he gives a counterexample with `std::string` where he uses the member function `size` instead. So in your example, you could provide a `size` member function which returns 5 instead of 8, and this would fit with the OP's question. I disagree therefore with the premise that his solution is inherently flawed, because you're relying on an assumption that it must use `sizeof`.

Comment: @Jbentley: he wants to call a hash function that takes a pointer and number of bytes. That is inherently wrong. Initially I had an example (see comment to the question) with internal padding, I just thought that it would be simpler to provide one with external padding here, I was wrong on that account, but I still claim that pointer+size is flawed, the only assumption I am doing is that he wants to hash a contiguous sequence of bytes. Fixed the code in the answer to have internal padding.

Comment: This discussion has been very educational. I'm not sure we can say it's wrong for a hash function to take a pointer and a number of bytes when that's exactly the interface used by popular hash functions; see code in [MurmurHash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MurmurHash) and [Jenkins hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function). But clearly simply passing an object pointer is broken--we have to make sure the hash input is packaged contiguously.